# Make a folder "Sharable" on Mac

Tags: mac, shared-folders, shared-libraries

My Mac got two different password protected users. Is there any way I can make the "music" folder a shared folder without copying/duplicating anything?

NOTE: When I right-click and "get info" on music folder, I can click make "shared folder" but then the Mac start yappin about "To publish this folder go to...". Is it dangerous to publish this folder or is it only me and the other user that can edit what's in the folder after I "publish" it.

Answer (score 0):

I just followed Apple's advice given on [this page](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1203) where they say:

If you're using Mac OS X, follow these steps:

> Quit iTunes. Go to your iTunes Media folder. 
>   By default, it's in ~/Music/iTunes. 
>   (This folder may be named iTunes Music if you created
>   your iTunes library in iTunes 9 or earlier.)   Note: "~" represents
>   your Home folder. Other users on your computer can't access these
>   locations. Drag the iTunes Media folder to a public location. For
>   example, you could move it to the Public folder in your Home folder
>   (~/Public) or to a location outside your Home folder that other users
>   can access (/Users/Shared). Important: Don't move the iTunes folder,
>   the iTunes library file, or the iTunes library.xml file. Open iTunes.
>   Choose iTunes > Preferences. Click Advanced. Click the Change button.
>   In the window that opens, go to your iTunes Media folder. Click Choose
>   or Open.

and I lost around 5GB because **every song got duplicated!** Thanks apple!

Answer (score 0):

You can make an alias by right clicking on the music folder and selecting `Make Alias`. Rename the alias to whatever you want and then the alias to the shared folder.

A similar result can be obtained via the /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app by making a symbolic link (symlink):

```
ln -s "/path/to/your/music/library" "/Users/Shared/Music"
```

Comment: Will the songs/folder get duplicated? I.e. will I lose a lot of space GB?

Comment: @LoveLearning No, neither of these methods copy anything, they just create a tiny file that points to somewhere else in your file system.

Comment: Aha... So the problem lies with I tunes duplicating everything

Comment: @LoveLearning Did you get duplicate files with one of my suggestions?

Comment: Hi, I haven't tried your method yet. But you know that iTunes got this duplicating problem right? I'm afraid it will duplicate no matter.

Comment: Any success like this?